# How do I know after running `apt-cache show <package>`, which repository in `sources.list` the package corresponds to?

Tags: linux, debian, package-management

How do I know after running `apt-cache show <package>`, which repository in `sources.list` the `<package>` and its `Filename:` field corresponds to?

In this case, there are few repositories in `sources.list`, so I could prepend the path `pool/main/c/cntlm/cntlm_0.92.3-1+b1_amd64.deb` to all of them, and check if it works.

But what if I had many repositories in `sources.list` - how would I see in what repository the package is located in?

**`apt-cache show cntlm`**:

```
parallels@debian-gnu-linux-vm:~$ apt-cache show cntlm
Package: cntlm
Source: cntlm (0.92.3-1)
Version: 0.92.3-1+b1
Installed-Size: 149
Maintainer: David Watson <dwatson@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Replaces: ntlmaps
Depends: adduser, libc6 (>= 2.14)
Description-en: Fast NTLM authentication proxy with tunneling
 Cntlm is a fast and efficient NTLM proxy, with support for TCP/IP tunneling,
 authenticated connection caching, ACLs, proper daemon logging and behaviour
 and much more. It has up to ten times faster responses than similar NTLM
 proxies, while using by orders or magnitude less RAM and CPU. Manual page
 contains detailed information.
Description-md5: a09ce14efcc2b3cdd95e19cd49ef5d70
Homepage: http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/
Tag: role::program, security::authentication, use::proxying
Section: net
Priority: optional
Filename: pool/main/c/cntlm/cntlm_0.92.3-1+b1_amd64.deb
Size: 64240
MD5sum: a32eae32fd459e472caf1e47330af6d9
SHA256: c0a10c545d42dacea0b6d4ebf7c088a1178e708083fd2e32f2c277dcc17f69f0
```

**`/etc/apt/sources.list`**:

```
parallels@debian-gnu-linux-vm:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 9.1.0 _Stretch_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20170722-11:31]/ stretch contrib main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib

# docker
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t determine this directly from the output of `apt-cache show`. There’s another `apt-cache` command which will tell you what versions are available in the various repositories, `policy`; those which carry the candidate version are all potential sources for the package shown by `show`.

```
apt-cache policy cntlm
```

will give the information you’re after.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. So, `apt-get policy` may list multiple versions of the same package, with the newest being the candidate? Suppose multiple repositories contain the package, which repository is chosen then? Is the repository chosen by the order they are listed in `sources.list` or in the output of `apt-get policy`? Will `apt-get policy` always display repository/packages in the order of `sources.list`?

Comment: The candidate is determined by the package priorities, it’s not necessarily the newest. I think `apt` uses the first repository in `sources.list` and `sources.list.d/...` that carries the requested version. `apt-get policy` displays versions from newest to oldest, then for each version, the repositories in decreasing order of priority.

Comment: What do you mean by "package priorities" in **The candidate is determined by the package priorities**? In any case, for any repository that shows up in `apt-cache policy` that has a package with the same version as the `Version:` field in `apt-cache show <package>`, the `Filename:` path component will applies and should be appended to the repositories' URL (in `apt-cache policy <package>`)?

Comment: I mean the [priorities given to packages from various origins](https://manpages.debian.org/apt/apt_preferences.5.en). And yes, you can retrieve a package by building the URL from a repository and the `Filename` entry.